# Javascript - if statement that checks if null, is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that looks like this

```
 Component comp = db.Components.Find(Model.ComponentID);
 Item i = db.Items.Find(Model.ItemID);

<script type="text/javascript">
 function clicked(e) {

            var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
            var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
            var compDiff = @Model.comp_qty - compQty;
            var compFuture = @comp.FSTK - compDiff;
            alert('compDiff = ' + compDiff )
                      if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce component ' + @comp.ComponentID + ' future stock from ' + @comp.FSTK+ ' to ' + compFuture))e.preventDefault();

                  if(@comp != null && @i == null) {
                      var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
                      var compDiff = @Model.comp_qty - compQty;
                      var compFuture = @comp.FSTK - compDiff;
                      if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce component ' + @comp.ComponentID + ' future stock to ' + compFuture)) e.preventDefault();
                  }
                  else if(@i !== null && @comp == null ) {
                      var itemQty = $('#itemQTY').val();
                      var itemDiff = @Model.item_qty - itemQty;
                      var itemFuture = @i.FSTK - itemDiff;
                      if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce item ' + @i.ItemID + ' future stock to ' + itemFuture))e.preventDefault();
                  }
                  else if(@i !== null && @comp !== null) {
                      var itemQty = $('#itemQTY').val();
                      var itemDiff = @Model.item_qty - itemQty;
                      var itemFuture = @i.FSTK - itemDiff;
                      var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
                      var compDiff = @Model.comp_qty - compQty;
                      var compFuture = @comp.FSTK - compDiff;

                      if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce component' + @comp.ComponentID + ' future stock to ' + compFuture + 'and reduce item' + @i.ItemID + ' future stock to ' + itemFuture))e.preventDefault();
                  }
              }
</script>
```

But for example in my situation 'i' is null.
So the else if statement is not met but it still gives me an error of
**'i is null'**. I have tried doing `@i != null` and `@i !== null` but it gives the error for both situations

Also the function is giving me the error on pageload. It should only go through that function when my button is clicked

Comment: This is the problem with mixing server-side and client-side code like this. Instead, either create an endpoint in your server-side code that you can hit via ajax, or write your server-side values to an object, and output that using JSON.

Comment: Would you be able to show me a mini example of what that would look like? @HereticMonkey

Comment: I'd probably just write, at the top of your `script`, `var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeOjbect(Model));`... Then you'd have, on the client side, the same model as you have at the server side. Of course, that depends a lot on what your `Model` object contains. If you need the database entities, like `i` and `comp`, just do the same thing. Might be a bit more difficult, since EF entities have circular references, if I'm not mistaken. You might need to create a dynamic object with just the properties you need.

Comment: thanks! @HereticMonkey I have to put in ``` var model = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));``` as the JsonConvert gives me an error other wise. But when I run the code I now get this error Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Comp' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Component_270714F13D00FDD4B1C51C5F401EC5CCA602DCA66A977683A435DAD46CD7E83C'. Path 'Components.CHP[0]'.'